# Can this be done with a group by clause?

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm refactoring a document processing app and  I think I see an opportunity  to substitute a query for a lot of code.   A db table contains a row for each  occurrence of a dictionary term in a document.  A row contains the character position in the document of the first letter of the dictionary entry and a code number that is associated with the  dictionary term.  For example here is a set of rows that resulted from processing  a single document.

```
doc        pos        code
55          20          44
55         169          44
55         328          44
55          86         174
55          98         393
55         566         393
```

The problem  is to return only the  rows with the first occurrence of each code.  So for this example rows one, four and five should  be returned. It 'feels' like a group by code could do this but I can't figure out the condition for a group by  that would select the  rows with the lowest pos for each code.
A query solution needs to  work only  for ms sqlserver.

Comment: "A query solution needs to work only for ms sqlserver"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select doc, code, min(pos) as pos
from t
group by doc, code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT doc, MIN(pos),code       
FROM Table1
group by doc, code
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cb8a/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a rdbms which supports window functions like `ROW_NUMBER`, here an example which works in sql-server 2005 upwards:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT doc, pos, code, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY doc,code Order By pos)
    from dbo.TableName
)
SELECT doc, pos, code
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

The advantage of a window function is that it's  more reable and maintainable than a `GROUP BY` and you can change the order easily or add other window functions. You can also use the `OVER` clause on aggregate functions, e.g.: `SUM(doc)OVER(PARTITION BY code)` and you can include all columns without needing to add it to the group-by or to apply aggregate functions.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cb8a/3/0)

You might want to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`, have a look yourself:

[**Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: +1. It could be `PARTITION BY doc, code`, the OP is not clear and the sample is too short to decide which of the two is needed.